# グーグルのapiのマーカーを使わずvector2Dを得る方法

Tags: javascript, google-maps

グーグルの　MARKER API　を使わずみせなくちゃいけないんですが
これが問題になっちゃったんですけど、マーカーの位置がちょっとだけ間違っていると見えまして
この　LOGIC　の問題じゃないかと思います。

下のリストはやってたことです

1. window.onmousemove, google.addEventListener("drag")で移動前後の中心座標の違いを比較し、"px"の値を取得する方法です。
2. 左上隅のlatとlngに基づいてマップ上のマーカーの値をドラッグ毎、またはマウス移動イベント毎に計算する方法です。

描かれたマーカーは、Google map api を使用して描かれたマーカーとまったく同じように移動する必要があります。

正確にベクトルを得る方法を教えてください

Comment: まとめると「Google Mapで [Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers?hl=ja) を使わずに地図上にマーカーを自作で描画しているが、スクロール・ドラッグ時に実際の地図からズレてしまう。標準のMarkerと同じように、スクロール・ドラッグしても正確な座標を示し続けるようにしたい」ということでしょうか。

Comment: @PicoSushi  
Yes, that’s right.
I solved this problem.
If you use the center_changed event instead of drag, onmousemove, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

center_changedをイベントを使用すると正常に動作します

drag, mousemove, center_changedイベントは
発生時点が似ているように見えますが、結果的には少しずつ違いました